# pointers as template arguments in c++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, arguments

I get a link error of an unresolved external symbol "reducedFraction(uint64_t*,uint64_t*)" from the following code.

in main.cpp I have:

```
template <typename T>  T greatestCommonFactor(T a, T b) {
    //make b the smaller
    T t;//temp
    if (b > a)
    {
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
    //archimedes method
    while (b != 0)
    {
        t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
void reduceFraction(T *a, T *b) {
    T gcf = greatestCommonFactor(*a, *b);
    *a /= gcf;
    *b /= gcf;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t numerator;
    uint64_t denominator;

    numerator = 121;
    denominator = 55;
    cout << numerator << " " << denominator << endl;

    reduceFraction(&numerator, &denominator);

    cout << numerator << " " << denominator << endl;
}
```

The functions greatestCommonFactor and reduceFraction work fine when I have "uint64_t" as just non-template function instead of "T". It turns out when I change just reduceFraction to a non-template function the link error now is with greatestCommonFactor.

Changing first line of reduceFraction to

```
auto gcf = greatestCommonFactor(*a, *b);
```

does not do the trick.

What am I doing wrong? It should be obvious that I am trying to reduce a fraction.  When I write the code as a non-template function it works just fine.  Thanks in advance.

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl reduceFraction(unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *)" (?reduceFraction@@YAXPA_K0@Z) referenced in function _main  visualStudioEuler   C:\Users\George\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\visualStudioEuler\visualStudioEuler\main.obj  1
```

A couple of side notes:
I am using visual studio community on windows 10 with code that was "ported" from CodeLite, if that helps. I have had some trouble with "stdafx.h" and other header files because of it.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: If you tried "auto gcf = greatestCommonFactor(*a, *b);", would it compile?

Comment: Your code [seems to work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/724d556bfd9d6b0e) (that is, if you provide the definition of `greatestCommonFactor()`) _(also, you're using MSVC... but I think even MSVC is capable of compiling this code ;) )_

Comment: @865719 [I second that](http://ideone.com/U81GtX)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  As it is right now this error is not reproducible.

Comment: Is this really the code you are trying to compile? Is really `reduceFraction` in the same file as `main` function, or is `reduceFraction` in a separate file, library?

Comment: The definition of `greatestCommonFactor` must be visible **at compile time** in the module containing `reduceFraction`.  The error message says it is not visible.  Your posted subset of your code, gives us no hint either way.  (there are some more complicated alternatives to making that visible at compile time.  But you obviously haven't done one of those, nor given us reason to believe you need one nor you would easily understand one.  So stick with make it visible at compile time.)

Comment: You put `reduceFraction` implementation in some `cpp` file and include a header with its declaration, do you?

Comment: Thanks much for checking out the code @865719.  This makes it look like problem is with linking rather than syntax.

Comment: Yes. [Your (new) code compiles and runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/735f71088f69df1a) as expected... I'd suggest that you have a look at the [Walkthrough: Creating a Standard C++ Program (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx). In my opinion, the project configuration has been messed at some point. In particular, you should (always) create an "empty project" (cf. step #4). This avoids polluting your project with all the _windows-specific_ stuff. (e.g. `stdafx.h`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works now. The problem was with the header files.  Has something to do with "stdafx.h". Sorry I can not give a better answer at this point. Only posting this in case someone else comes across a similar problem and is uncertain of their code. Thank you all for your help!